# calling a function in Python?

Tags: python, function, python-3.5

I don't know how to call the functions below I listed a box with what I want to do but don't know how to.

```
import random
import time

startingP_health = 30
startingE_health = 30

def player_attack():
    global startingE_health
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("What ability would you like to use? (free speach(fs), capatalism(c), or punch(p)")
    ability_choice = input()

    if(ability_choice == "fs"):
        enemy_health = startingE_health-3
        enemy_heath = int(enemy_health)
    elif(ability_choice == "c"):
        enemy_health = startingE_health-(random.randint(1,6))
        enemy_heath = int(enemy_health)
    elif(ability_choice == "p"):
        enemy_health = startingE_health-(random.randint(2,4))
        enemy_heath = int(enemy_health)
    else:
        print("you fell.")

    time.sleep(1)

    print ("Enemie's health is now: ",enemy_health)
    print("")

    return int(enemy_health)


def enemy_attack():
    global startingP_health
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("Enemy kicks you")
    print("")
    player_health = startingP_health - (random.randint(1,3)
    player_health = int(player_health)
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("Your health is now ",player_health)
    print ("")
    return int(player_health)

def battle_trotsky():
    global player_health
    print ("Enemy appears")
    print ("")
    time.sleep(1)
    while player_health > 0 and enemy_health > 0:
        ##############################
        #call function player_attack
        #call enemy_attack
        ##############################
        if player_health <=0:
            break
        if enemy_health <= 0:
            time.sleep(1)
            print ("You have killed the enemy")

        if player_health <= 0:
            print("Sorry you failed the mission you must restart the mission"))

    ################################
    #initate function sequence
    ################################
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If the code is working, you may wish to consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Otherwise, please include a detailed and specific description of what is wrong.

Comment: @leaf I wanted to create a game that basically 3 enemies appear before you, you choose 1 out of 3 attack types , continuous battle with updated health every attack until one dies. story type game but I can add the storyline just wanted the battle mechanics working and its not :(.Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
import time
```

You need to declare `enemy_health` and `player_health` as globals so they persist:

```
startingP_health = 30
startingE_health = 30
enemy_health = startingE_health
player_health = startingP_health
```

This function doesn't have to return anything, since you declare `global enemy_health` and then assign it the new value:

```
def player_attack():
    global enemy_health
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("What ability would you like to use? (free speech(fs), capitalism(c), or punch(p)")
    ability_choice = input()
```

This wasn't working because you were doing `enemy_health = starting health - 3`, which means every round it would start again from the starting health. Instead here, `-=` is subtract from the current value: `enemy_health = enemy_health - 3`:

```
    if(ability_choice == "fs"):
        enemy_health -= 3
    elif(ability_choice == "c"):
        enemy_health -= random.randint(1,6)
    elif(ability_choice == "p"):
        enemy_health -= random.randint(2,4)
    else:
        print("you fell.")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("Enemy's health is now: ",enemy_health)
    print("")


def enemy_attack():
    global player_health
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("Enemy kicks you")
    print ("")
    player_health -= random.randint(1,3)
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("Your health is now ",player_health)
    print ("")

def battle_trotsky():
    global player_health 
    global enemy_health 
    print ("Enemy appears")
    print ("")
    time.sleep(1)
    while player_health > 0 and enemy_health > 0:
```

Functions are called via `name()`, as seen:

```
        player_attack()
        enemy_attack()
        if enemy_health <= 0:
            time.sleep(1)
            print ("You have killed the enemy")

        if player_health <= 0:
            print("Sorry you failed the mission you must restart the mission")

battle_trotsky()
```

Comment: 2Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed to be explained, listen I'm trying to make a game with  multiple enemies and a corny story line, do you think you could help me in some parts, or should I just post here when I'm stuck. Honestly thanks for helping me, no matter your answer

Comment: @Uri.K Put in the effort to figure it out yourself. If you show effort towards your goal, people are much more likely to help :) And good luck... everyone had to start at square one!

Answer (score 0):

This is a not a good question for this site as it is not specific, but I feel compelled to fixed this code by a deep power. I'm not sure why you're doing the sleeps, the print("") statements can be replaced with a '\n' in the previous prints, and you are continuously reassigning player health to the starting health - number, which will never reach 0, so you must make the healths global.

Here's a working example

```
import random

player_health = 30
enemy_health = 30

def player_attack():
    global enemy_health
    ability_choice = input("What ability would you like to use? (free speach(fs), capatalism(c), or punch(p)")

    if(ability_choice == "fs"):
        enemy_health -= 3
    elif(ability_choice == "c"):
        enemy_health -= random.randint(1,6)
    elif(ability_choice == "p"):
        enemy_health -= random.randint(2,4)
    else:
        print("you fell.")
    print ("Enemy's health is now: "+str(enemy_health)+'\n')

def enemy_attack():
    global player_health
    print ("Enemy kicks you")
    player_health -= random.randint(1,3)
    print ("Your health is now "+str(player_health)+"\n")

def battle_trotsky():
    print ("Enemy appears\n")
    while player_health > 0 and enemy_health > 0:
        player_attack()
        if check_game_over():
            return
        enemy_attack()
        if check_game_over():
            return

def check_game_over():
    global player_health, enemy_health
    if enemy_health <= 0:
        print ("You have killed the enemy\n")
        return True
    elif player_health <= 0:
        print("Sorry you failed the mission you must restart the mission")
        return True
    else:
        return False

if __name__=='__main__':
    battle_trotsky()
```

Comment: `raw_input()` is python2. OP specified python3, where `input()` is what you want

Comment: I wanted to create a game that basically 3 enemies appear before you you choose 1 out of 3 attack types , continuous battle with updated health every attack until one dies. I started learning python a week ago and I might need to relearn somethings I guess , but you think you could help me finishing the code , it probably for you take 3 minutes . I don't want to ask too much for you but if you have time.

Comment: This code should work for one enemy and you, the player. Take the time to understand the changes and make the attempt to implement the rest yourself. Nobody ever said learning is easy ;)

Comment: @ChrisKenyon You've made some pretty substantial changes to the structure of the program. It would probably be worthwhile to explain **why** they make the program better overall.